# Can't Install Plugins in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to get Flutter/Dart plugins set up in Android Studio but I'm having a ton of trouble.

The Plugin Browser doesn't work at all. I tried with different internet connections and with my firewall totally off but still got nothing. Also tried reinstalling fully to no avail. I added a [repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/androidstudio) manually but it doesn't connect to it. I *can* go to that link in my web browser without any issue.

I tried installing the Dart/Flutter plugins from the disk too and it throws a different error

```
Plugin 'Dart' is incompatible with this installation
```

I've also tried enabling "auto-detect proxy settings" in the HTML Proxy settings and this didn't help either.

I'm running the latest version of Android Studio (3.5.3) on a Windows 10 Home machine. I tried to downgrade to 3.1.2 and that didn't help either.

Not sure what to do to get this working - any help would be awesome!

Comment: What AS version do you have? Is it some beta? or even canary version?

Comment: @pskink Hi! I'm running the latest stable version - 3.5.3.

Comment: for 3.5 i have [41.1.2](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/update/72107) - download it from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions

Comment: and dart is [191.8593](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart/update/70795)

Comment: Thanks @pskink! I can install those. However, installing that version of the Dart plugin causes Android Studio to start crashing on launch with a large java error being thrown. Flutter installs fine though (seemingly).

Comment: those are versions i have for AS 3.5 and AS works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by reinstalling again. Not sure what fixed it sepcifically since I already had tried reinstalling, but it worked this time around. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go through the link https://medium.com/flutterpub/installing-flutter-in-android-studio-ec135911ceea. It is just a simple wizard to setup flutter in Android Studio.

Comment: Hi Kamal - thank you for replying! Unfortunately, my issue is that when I go into that plugin browser, nothing shows up. It looks like the plugin browser isn't able to connect to the repository. Because of this, I can't search for the Flutter or Dart plugin to install it.

Comment: You mean you are not able to see the all plugin list in the MarketPlace tab? I am also facing the same issue now, just tried opening market place. May be there is some temporary issue that it is not able to connect with the plugins repository.